# Gmail is adding an injected stylesheet span.gc-cs-link to make phone numbers into links. How can I override this styling?

Tags: css, email, gmail

I have tried to add styling to  tag and  tag around the phone number and that does not work. I also tried adding a script before and after calling the class as .span.gc-cs-link {color:#color;} but that also does not work. I am running chrome with a google voice extension - could that be what is causing it? Either way it would be nice to know how injected stylesheets work and how to override their styling.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPozQ.png)

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow :)Give the code snippets or screenshots to help viewers understand the problem. Also mention why you are working on gmail styling etc .,

Comment: @skeptor screenshot added

Answer (score 0):

You can use this HTML encoded dash in place of the - character to avoid the issue:

```
&#8209;
```

555‑555‑5555 would be

```
555&#8209;555&#8209;5555
```